# Discord.py bot take file as argument to command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need to take a file as an argument to a discord bot command by attaching it to the command text. How would I do this? I've currently got this code however the file is not picked up as an argument:

```py
@bot.command()
async def upload_file(ctx, file:discord.File):
    f = file.fp
    txt = f.read().decode("utf-8")
    file.close()
    print(txt)
```

**Why is the file not being passed as an argument?**

And, more importantly, how can I make it so it is?

The exact error is as follows:

```
Ignoring exception in command upload_file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 721, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 685, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 599, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 445, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: file is a required argument that is missing.
`
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=file#file ?

Comment: @eagle33322 yes I've looked at that and it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read through the discord py documentation some and I believe you are going about this the wrong way. Command arguments are simply parsed via the plain text context of the message that it sees, so placing an attachment on there will not be picked up in this way, but you will still be able to do what you want, albeit in a different way.

The key is the context argument of the command (ctx): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context

Looking at the documentation, you will see it has an instance of Message: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message, which contains a list of Attachments: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment

Attachments have a url parameter which store where the attachment is uploaded to discord (which is the key to why you can't take a file as a parameter, attachments are uploaded to discord's servers independently of your discord bot). The url parameter will enable you to download the contents of said file and do whatever processing you would like to do with it, however. So here is some pseudocode that should work (again, this is all from a cursory glance at the docs) using the requests module to download the attachment:

```
@bot.command()
async def upload_file(ctx):
    attachment_url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    file_request = requests.get(attachment_url)
    print(file_request.content)
```

And to recap, when you send this command to your bot with an attachment, that attachment gets uploaded to discords servers and a url and some other info gets sent with the message to your command bot (and anyone else listening). To get the actual file data, you then have to download the file from that url. From there, you can do whatever you want with it. Note that the requests library is 3rd party, but much better (imo) than the builtin support for http. I would also suggest you add some edge case handling to your command to ensure there is actually an attachment to process, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work with the file locally, there is a very simple way:
In `Context`:
The `Message` object has an attribute called an `attachments`. 
List of `discord.Attachment` (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment)

*I dunno why, but it will all time list of one object*

It has a `save` function that accepts `io.BufferedIOBase` or `os.PathLike` (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.save)

And already depending on the transferred object saves the file locally
Then you can do with it everything you want